# Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

hibernate

```
@NamedQuery(name = "EkRequest.getAllCompletedKycRequestsByStatus", query = "select ekr.ekId,   ekr.serviceLocation, ekr.phoneNo,ekr.email,"
                + "ekr.fullName, ekr.createdCustodyCode, ekr.referCode, r.associatedBroker.fullName from EKYCRequest ekr JOIN ekr.referer r where"
                                + " status = :ekStatus and completedAt between :ekFromDate and :ekToDate order by ekr.completedAt desc")
```

foreign key

```
@ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "REFERER_ID")
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
        @ToString.Exclude
        EKReferer referer;
```

Respository

```
public List<EKYCRequest> findAllEkRequestsByCompleted(LocalDate fromDate, LocalDate toDate,
            EKYCRequest.EKStatus status, boolean foreignInvestor) {

        LocalDateTime fromDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(fromDate, LocalTime.MIN);
        LocalDateTime toDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(toDate, LocalTime.MAX);
        var list = em.createNamedQuery("EkRequest.getAllCompletedKycRequestsByStatus", EKYCRequest.class)
                .setParameter("ekFromDate", fromDateTime)
                .setParameter("ekToDate", toDateTime)
                .setParameter("ekStatus", status)
                .getResultList();
        if (foreignInvestor) {
            return list.stream().filter(r -> r.getForeignInvestor() == Boolean.TRUE).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else {
            return list.stream().filter(r -> r.getForeignInvestor() != Boolean.TRUE).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

Fix error:
Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [com.nguyennp.domain.ekyc.EKYCRequest]